# Eclipse, Python and the Google SDK

Tags: python, eclipse, web-applications, sdk

How do I get Eclipse to load the Google python SDK?

I am using OSX 10.6, I have Eclipse (helios) and I have downloaded the GoogleAppEngineLauncher and the Eclipse plugin.

When I try to start a new web app project its asks for the SDK. I enter my location as follows:

`/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/ 
GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine`

But all I get is Failed to initialize!

What I have Done wrong? any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to install the Google App Engine SDK/Launcher separately if using Eclipse.  The Google Plugin for Eclipse will install the App Engine SDK/Launcher for you:

http://code.google.com/eclipse/

In the event you need to install them separately, it does appear you've got a space in your path between "Resources" and "GoogleApeEngine-default.bundle".  Also, have you verified the path in question, the path to google_appenine, is valid?

Comment: The path was /usr/local/google_appengine. This is then altered to the path above (without the space) but it still says failed to initialize. So the path is valid. Also, In the GoogleAppEngineLauncher I ran the Symlink which told me that should be the correct path to the SDK. But still no luck

Comment: Well, having the wrong path in there would obviously give a failure when trying to use it.  ;)

Comment: The path should be fine. Both the GoogleAppEngineLauncher and help files have told me that that is the link to use, I am probably missing something obvious....